# Rvest not returning all html_nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Attempting to scrape [this site](http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/alabama/) for vote results using `rvest`. Using selector gadget

[image]

This looks like the right node--so I tried the following:

```
library(plyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

res <- "http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/alabama/" %>% 
  read_html
```

I'm going to need the county names for the nodes, so I'll scrape them first

```
cnames <- res %>% 
  html_nodes("h4") %>% 
  html_text %>% 
  extract(str_detect(., "County"))
```

And then scrape the site via an `llply` call

```
cnames %>% 
  str_sub(, str_locate(., fixed(" "))[, 1] - 1) %>% 
  str_c("#county", 
    .,
    " .results-popular") %>% 
  llply(failwith(NULL,
             function(i)
               res %>% 
                html_nodes(i) %>% 
                html_text))
```

But the resulting object only provides 10 sets of results:

```
[[1]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[2]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[4]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[5]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[6]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[7]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[8]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[9]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[10]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0"

[[11]]
character(0)

[[12]]
character(0)
```

How do I scrape the remaining results?

Comment: Sure, but are elements 11 through 67 `character(0)`?

Comment: Those nodes have an "is-loading" attribute and are probably loaded asynchronously. You will have to figure out a way to download the page once it is fully rendered.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/dc62bb2b35617e9badc5) might be helpful.

Comment: It seems like some of those tables take a bit longer to load. I wonder if you need to use RSelenium and then sleep for 5 seconds